# Vue3 - Using beforeRouteEnter to prevent flashing content

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-component, passport.js, vue-router

I am using Vue with axios like

```
[...]
import VueAxios from "vue-axios";
import axios from "@/axios";


createApp(App)
  .use(store)
  .use(router)
  .use(VueAxios, axios)
  .mount("#app");
[...]
```

which works really great globally like `this.axios...` everywhere. I am also using Passport for authentification and in my protected route I would like to call my Express-endpoint `.../api/is-authenticated` to check if the user is logged in or not.

To make this work I would like to use the beforeRouteEnter-navigation guard, but unfortunately I can't call this in there.

Right now I am having in in the mounted-hook, which feels wrong. Is there any solution with keeping my code straight and clean?

I'd appreciate a hint. Thanks.

Edit: This worked for me.

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next((vm) => {
      var self = vm;

      self
        .axios({ method: "get", url: "authenticate" })
        .then() //nothing needed here to continue?
        .catch((error) => {
          switch (error.response.status) {
            case 401: {
              return { name: "Authentification" }; //redirect
              //break;
            }

            default: {
              return false; //abort navigation
              //break;
            }
          }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`beforeRouteEnter`](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) there is access to the component instance by passing a callback to `next`.  So instead of `this.axios`, use the following:

```js
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
  next(vm => {
    console.log(vm.axios);    // `vm` is the instance
  })
}
```

Here's a pseudo-example with an async request.  I prefer async/await syntax but this will make it clearer what's happening:

```js
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
  const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
  // ✅ Routing has not changed at all yet, still looking at last view
  axios.get(url).then(res => {
    // ✅ async request complete, still haven't changed views
    // Now test the result in some way
    if (res.data.length > 10) {  
      // Passed the test.  Carry on with routing
      next(vm => {
        vm.myData = res.data; // Setting a property before the component loads
      })
    } else {
      // Didn't like the result, redirect
      next('/')
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: May I ask about a comment about my code above? There is nothing needed in .then()? I mean it works, I am not sure if it is to supposed to be like that.

Comment: Sometimes layout of my protected route flashes before it redirects to my login page. This is what I was hoping to prevent with the navigation guard.

Comment: You can remove the `.then` if you don't need it.  But I don't see how the code would help with anything because it makes an axios call but does nothing with it.  Also the `return false` should not abort navigation, you should use `next()` to go to another route